# Python implementing a function to return a list where y[i] is the number of prime numbers <= to i

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, primes

c) Using your function in Part (b), implement the function primesCount(n), which given
a integer n, returns the length-n list y, given by y[i] = the number of prime numbers
less than or equal to i, for i = 0, 1, . . . , n − 1.
Sample Input/Output:
Enter a number: 6
[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3]

Part (b) function:

```
def generatePrimes(n):

    prime = [False for i in range(n)]
    I = []
    for i in range(2, n):
       if i > 1:
           for j in range(2, int(math.sqrt(i))+1):
               if i % j == 0:
                   break
           else:
               I.append(i)
               prime[i] = True
    return prime
```

All of the code (part b + part c function):

```
import math

def generatePrimes(n):
    prime = [False for i in range(n)]  # creates a list of n-length all consisting of F elem
    I = []
    for i in range(2, n):
       if i > 1:
           for j in range(2, int(math.sqrt(i))+1):
               if i % j == 0:
                   break
           else:
               I.append(i)   # unecessary
               prime[i] = True #change False to True if number is prime
    return prime   # return the list (indexes with False are composite numbers while indexes 
                    with True are prime number

def primesCount(n):
    I = []
    for i in range(n):
        I.append(generatePrimes(i))
    return I
   
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print(primesCount(n))
```

**expected input/output:**

```
input: Enter a number: 6 

output: [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3]
```

**actual input/output:**

```
input: Enter a number: 6 

output: [[], [False], [False, False], [False, False, True],[False, False, True, True]]
```

What I need is to convert the False and True to integers so for example False + False + False + True + True = 0 + 0 + 1 + 1 = 2

I would like to convert the above output to
[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3]   ( [False] = 0, [False + False] = 0, [False, False, True] = 1...)

Been scratching my head for hours on this can't seem to get it working

Comment: `itertools.accumulate(generatePrimes(6))` does most of the work.

Comment: It looks like you need neither of the two ``I`` nor ``primes``. Either keep a running count as you compute primes, or use the ``generatePrimes`` from b) and take a running count of that.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the challenge here. The number of primes lower than 6 is 3 - specifically 2, 3 & 5. So I'm confused by the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your code. Please look into it

```
import math

def generatePrimes(n):
    prime = [False for i in range(n)]  # creates a list of n-length all consisting of F elem
    I = []
     
    for i in range(2, n):
       if i > 1:
           for j in range(2, int(math.sqrt(i))+1):
               if i % j == 0:
                   break
           else:
               I.append(i)   # unecessary
               prime[i] = True #change False to True if number is prime
    return prime   # return the list (indexes with False are composite numbers while indexes 
                    #with True are prime number

def primesCount(n):
    I = []
    for i in range(n+1):
        if len(generatePrimes(i)):
            I.append(sum(generatePrimes(i)))
    return I
   
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print(primesCount(n))
```

Comment: I managed to solve it, but thanks for the code this one seems more efficient than mine. Can you briefly explain what the "if len(generatePrimes(i))" does?

Comment: It checks to see if generatePrimes(i) returned an array of length > 0.

Answer (score -1):

```
def generatePrimes(n):
    prime = [False for i in range(n)]  # creates a list of n-length all consisting of F elem
    I = []
    for i in range(2, n):
       if i > 1:
           for j in range(2, int(math.sqrt(i))+1):
               if i % j == 0:
                   break
           else:
               I.append(i)   # unecessary
               prime[i] = True #change False to True if number is prime


    final_output = []
    counter = 0
    for value in prime:
        if prime:
            counter += 1
    final_output.append(counter)

    return final_output
```

Just loop through each value and iterate a counter if the value is true. Put this before you return the prime value.